# How can I select the row from a table whose 1 field is maximum or minimum?

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a field name `rt_stars` which includes integer anyone between 1 to 5. Suppose there are 5 rows having `rt_stars` `4,4,3,2,1` respectively. Here, 4 is the highest and 1 is the lowest. If I want to select the row with the maximum value 4 how can I do that? Since there are two `4` here the last one will be selected. Can I have query something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE MAX(rt_stars) ORDER BY rt_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I know this is wrong but that's how I want to select all the values from the rows if the `rt_stars` field has the maximum value in it. How can I achieve this kind of a query?

Comment: How do you differentiate between the two that have `4`; of which one is the latest? datetime field? Auto-incremental ID field?

Comment: autoincremental... `rt_id` is autoincremental...

Comment: I think you don't need to use `MAX()` .. instead you just order by `rt_stars DESC, rt_id DESC` and `LIMIT 1`

Comment: can order by with multiple values??

Comment: yes of course can.. see @Gordon's answer

Comment: Please don't spam tag. I've edited the others besides "mysql" out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select one row using:

```
select r.*
from ratings r
order by rt_stars desc, rt_id desc
limit 1;
```

The problem with your query is that you cannot use `max()` in the `where` clause.  Beyond that, you don't need aggregation at all -- just ordering the rows and then selecting the first one.

Comment: I think a simpler version would be `SELECT * FROM ratings ORDER BY rt_stars DESC, rt_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Your answer was perfect but lets just keep it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows with the maximum stars you can do:

```
select *
from ratings
where rt_stars = (select max(rt_stars) from ratings)
```

If you just want one of them randomly you can do:

```
select *
from ratings
order by rt_stars desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the below SQL code will help.

```
SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE rt_stars = MAX(rt_stars) ORDER BY rt_id DESC;
```

Sorry the code modified below

```
SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE rt_stars = ( SELECT MAX( user_05_pk ) FROM ratings )
 ORDER BY rt_id DESC;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It returns `Query Error: Error: ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function`